How to convert jsonschema to json using java for V202012 version?
I am trying to convert json schema to json for version V202012 which is the latest version. Is there any java library supports for this conversion.
Example of schema 12

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/arrays.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "description": "A representation of a person, company, organization, or place",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "fruits": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "vegetables": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/$defs/veggie" }
    }
  },
  "$defs": {
    "veggie": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "veggieName", "veggieLike" ],
      "properties": {
        "veggieName": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The name of the vegetable."
        },
        "veggieLike": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "description": "Do I like this vegetable?"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to

```
{
  "fruits": [
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB"    
  ],
  "vegetables": [
    {
      "veggieName": "ABCDE",
      "veggieLike": false
    },
    {
      "veggieName": "ABCDEFGHIJK",
      "veggieLike": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I could see the conversion till schema v7 and couldn't find solution for V202012.
I tried to look in to the bitbucket but not able to find the solution

you can use mockturtle.net
Save your JSON Schema file in a .json and then upload the file to the tool.  It outputs an array of json. One thing to note is the output is a collection(array) of the schema, so it doesn't respect the root type, it's always a collection. You can easily remove the [] and then you have the json instance.

Thanks for the response. I am looking for a code to convert in Java.
